# Tridion UI 2012 - Error "The item tcm:280-29837-64 does not exist."

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When we are trying to create a new page through a PageType in Tridion UI.It is throwing below error --

```
"The item tcm:280-29837-64 does not exist."
```

Is it the Id of the page which i want to create,as it is no more exists in the tridion?

Could any body help me out in this regard ?

Note :-we defined the pagetype to those pages which already exist and published.

**Edit-1** When we click on the 'Create Page' button(see the attached screenshot), above mentioned error Pops up.

[image]

In the cd_core.log file  below error and warning comes --

ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file 'cd_ambient_conf.xml' with schema 'schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ClaimStoreProvider'. One of '{Cookies}' is expected.

WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised

**Edit-2** Now errors related to AmbientDataWork are resolved but we are still getting same issue. There are two options in UI (a) "New Page" (b) Create and insert Content.  This error also comes when we go with the option "Create and Insert Content". On each click of "Create Page" or "Create and insert Content" it generate  a new Id(XXX-59248 -64 then XXX-59249- 64 etc) for page and same way for component also and throws above mentioned error message.

> Note:- We are using IIS 6.

**Edit-3** - I am using VB script in my page templates.

Comment: Where do you get the error? Is there any additional logging or a stack trace, for example in the deployer or storage log of your odata upload service (the one that writes to the session preview DB)?

Comment: Thanks Frank for you quick reply ,hope above edit in the question can provide you a bit more detail.

Comment: So the next step will typically be to look if the configuration file for your Ambient Data Framework. Clearly something is not correctly configured there. If you want us to look at it, dump the file in the question. But be aware the Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for programming questions and not the best place to help you troubleshoot this type of installation issue.

Comment: Is this happening to only when use a particular page type or any page type?

Comment: Have you tried to check is item with this ID actually exist in TCM?

Comment: Hi Ram. Do not focus yourself on those errors you see in the cd_core.log as they do not interfere at all with Preview. If you want to make sure the issue is not related to CD please to the following test: get to that point where you need to click your button, then clean all your CD logs (the ones on the Staging site but also the ones on the Preview Webservice), then click on "Create Page" and check what logging you have in the CD logs. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Frank-Issues related to Ambient data framework are resolved.But no luck

Comment: @Boris -Yes,i checked,it is not in TCM.

Comment: @Sea_gull -I followed all your suggested steps, nothing is logged in these log files.

Comment: I am going to update this question again with my new findings.I am going to update the question again with few more finding .

Comment: @RamG , it is happening with each type of page type.

Comment: Did you check your broker session  preview DB config (different from broker db) in preview site? When you create a page or insert content are they being stored in session DB. Did you check the Odata session preview WS logs?

Comment: @RamG, When I create a page/ insert content nothing get stored in the session preview DB and  no log file get created specific to this session preview odata service. I am a bit in doubt that the service is properly integrated in the whole cycle or not. Is there any way to check this service individually?

Comment: i'm not sure you could check the session web service directly. Do you have your PublicationTarget setup with Odata.svc ? When you edit or create any content via preview CMS UI extension will call session preview WS and web service will store the information in session broker db and your preview site is also configured with session preview db (session wrapper) and gets that information. You should check the log config and get that corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is using VB script page template,it is required to install UI_2012.0.0.81248 hotfixes to create new pages in UI 2012.
I was not aware about this so fact of using VB script is not mentioned anywhere in the question .So I am updating my question again to assist community member in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It "looks like" the creation of the page somehow fails on the CM side (but i'm doing an awful lot of interpretation here based on very limited data...).

Can you verify
1. that you can create pages in the content management explorer in the publication with ID 280
2. that your blueprint context settings for UI 2012 are correct (should the new page/component be created in the publication with ID 280?)
3. that you have no workflow or event system interfering with the creation of the page

I would also expect an event log entry in the Tridion/Tridion Content Manager event log which would contain a detailed stack trace...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I was out of office from last few days .i got the problem resolved and going to put my answer here.